# SQL Server Pattern Matching on Joins

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a series of identifiers in the format AAAA-NNN-AAA.

I want to join this to another table on the identifier but where each NNN contains 1,2 or 3 in either the second or third position within NNN.

So ABCD-010 would match ABCD-010 or ABCD-011 or ABCD-001 etc but not ABCD-121 or ABCD-003

I've look at `Like` obviously and `PATINDEX` but wondered if there was a standard 'efficient' method ?

Comment: So `NNN` first digit always will be 0? You provided `AAAA-NNN-AAA` format, but your sample data have only `AAAA-NNN` like `ABCD-010`. Try to provide more sample data and be more accurate.

Comment: In the questionI stated 1, 2 or 3 in either the second or third position within NNN ? I thong something like SUBSTRING(val, 6,3) like '%1%'  is going to work for me - I just wondered if there was a better method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way how you can achieve is, something like this:

```
create table #t1
(
    id nvarchar(max)
)
create table #t2 
(
    id nvarchar(max)
)
insert into #t1 values('ABCD-010')
insert into #t2 values('ABCD-021')

select *
from #t1 t1
join #t2 t2 on left(t1.id,4) = left(t2.id,4)
     and (cast(right(t2.id, 1) as int) in (1,2,3) or cast(left(right(t2.id, 2),1) as int) in (1,2,3))
```

Comment: I went with the substring method in the end but this is equally valid. Thanks for your input.